# Can I send events to EventBridge via Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I want to simply send an event from a lambda function TO an event bridge. Every thing that I search online is the other way around. And If I go to the AWS console and try to find lambda as an event source, nothing comes up.

Can I send a custom event to an event bridge from Lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, but only to a [custom EB bus](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-event-bus.html) and using AWS SDK's [put_events](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/events.html#EventBridge.Client.put_events). In other words, you have to do it programmatically. There is no automatic integration between lambda and custom EB bus.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like AWS might have changed the restriction around only sending to a custom EventBridge bus.

> You can create a custom event bus to receive events from your
> applications. **Your applications can also send events to the default
> event bus.** When you create an event bus, you can attach a
> resource-based policy to grant permissions to other accounts. Then
> other accounts can send events to the event bus in the current
> account.